# Changing a cell value in pandas column based on multiple rows grouping condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that contains three columns:

```
import pandas as pd
di={'id':[1,1,2,3,4,4],'b':['Sydney','Bexley','Arncliffe','Hurstville','Bexley North','Carlton'],
   'c':['contra','contra','contra_approved','contra','contra_approved','contra']}

df=pd.DataFrame(di)
df.head(10)


id  b             c
1   Sydney        contra
1   Bexley        contra
2   Arncliffe     contra_approved
3   Hurstville    contra
4   Bexley North  contra_approved
4   Carlton       contra
```

Each **id** should have a keyword *contra_approved* in the column *'c'*.

- For an id with one value with the keyword '*contra*', I need to change to *contra_approved* (e.g. id **3**)
- For an id with multiple rows with the keyword contra and without any of them being *contra_approved*, I need to change the first occurrence in the **id** related rows to *contra_approved* (e.g. id **1**).

The final dataframe would be:

```
id  b             c
1   Sydney        contra_approved
1   Bexley        contra
2   Arncliffe     contra_approved
3   Hurstville    contra_approved
4   Bexley North  contra_approved
4   Carlton       contra
```

How to interpret the following logic in pandas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
def f(d):
    if "contra_approved" not in d["c"].unique():
        d.loc[d.index[0], "c"] = "contra_approved"
    return d

df = df.groupby("id").apply(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
# check if all rows within same `id` have `c==contra`
g = df['c'].eq('contra').groupby(df['id']).transform('all')

# switch the first of those group into `contra_approved` 
# regardless of counts
df.loc[g & (~df.duplicated('id')), 'c'] = 'contra_approved'
```

Output:

```
   id             b                c
0   1        Sydney  contra_approved
1   1        Bexley           contra
2   2     Arncliffe  contra_approved
3   3    Hurstville  contra_approved
4   4  Bexley North  contra_approved
5   4       Carlton           contra
```

Answer (score 0):

```
g=df.groupby('id').head(1)
df[~df.isin(g)].dropna().append(g.replace(regex='^contra$',value='contra_approved')).sort_values(by='id')


   id             b                c
1  1.0        Bexley           contra
0  1.0        Sydney  contra_approved
2  2.0     Arncliffe  contra_approved
3  3.0    Hurstville  contra_approved
5  4.0       Carlton           contra
4  4.0  Bexley North  contra_approved
```

How it works

1. `g=df.groupby('id').head(1)`#Isolate the  first in each group
2. `g.replace(regex='^contra$',value='contra_approved')`#replace contra in g
3. `df[~df.isin(g)]`#Isolate those not on the first in each group
4. combine outcome of  step two and three

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
cond = df.groupby('id').cumcount().eq(0) 
       & ~df.id.isin(df.loc[df.c.eq('contra_approved'),'id'])
df.loc[cond,'c']='contra_approved'
df
Out[146]: 
   id             b                c
0   1        Sydney  contra_approved
1   1        Bexley           contra
2   2     Arncliffe  contra_approved
3   3    Hurstville  contra_approved
4   4  Bexley North  contra_approved
5   4       Carlton           contra
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, since it does not check if there is "contra_approved" in an id group.